# Non-isolated singularity points

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble understanding non-isolated singularity points. An isolated singularity point I do kind of understand, it is when: a point $z_0$ is said to be isolated if $z_0$ is a singular point and has a neighborhood throughout which $f$ is analytic except at $z_0$. For example, why would $\text{tan}(1/z),\ \text{log}(z),\text{or even}\ \frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{z})}$ have a non-isolated singularity point?

Comment: yes! but $e^{1/z}$ has essential singularity at $z=0$ as you expand it in laurent series expansion. number of negative terms are infinitely many

Comment: @CityOfGod I havent yet heard of essential singularity, but it isnt far removed from this section. I am going to look it up now.

Comment: [Branch points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point) are examples of non-isolated singularity points. Not only is there no [punctured neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctured_neighbourhood#Punctured_neighbourhood) of the branch point in which a function can be made analytic, there is no punctured neighborhood of the branch point in which a function can be made *continuous*!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\tan(1/z)$ has a non-isolated singularity at $z=0$, which is the limit of the singularities at $\dfrac{2}{\pi}, \dfrac{2}{3\pi}, \dfrac{2}{5\pi}, \ldots$.

The singularity of $\log(z)$ at $z=0$ is a branch point: this is on a curve  where
any particular branch of $\log(z)$ is discontinuous (e.g. the negative real axis in the case of the principal branch).

Comment: Allegedly there is a third type of a non-isolated singularity, known as 'boundary' points. Can you give an example of a function with such a singularity?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$.  See [lacunary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).

Comment: Lacunary function is new to me, thank you.

Answer (score -3):

A non-isolated singularity is where you can not have any further neighborhood without encountering another singularity

Comment: Idk why this is downvoted so much - it captures the gist. A nonisolated singularity is one where you don't have a punctured disk that doesnt have another singularity